# Upload image php

Tags: php, image, upload

I'm trying to upload an image in a specific folder, but I'm getting nothing, not even an error message, when I click on upload button I get a blank page, and that's it, What am I missing?

```
 <?php if ((isset($_POST["enviado"])) && ($_POST["enviado"] == "form2")) {
    $nome_arquivo = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],  "../legendofgames/documentos/games/".$nome_arquivo);
?>

    <script>
    opener.document.form2.strImage.value="<?php echo $nome_arquivo; ?>";
    self.close();
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {?>
```

.

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form2">

<p>
<input name="userfile" type="file" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Upload Image" />
</p>
<input type="hidden" name="enviado" value="form2" />
</form>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error after `move_uploaded_file()`.

Comment: I'm still getting nothing, any ideas?

Comment: Ever considered [enabling error_reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)?

Comment: There's no error, I've added <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?> in the code, but it shows nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.turn on error reporting in php.ini file or add this line at first:

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
```

2.It seems that u have an syntax error on line 4: forget to close php code by **?>**

```
<?php if ((isset($_POST["enviado"])) && ($_POST["enviado"] == "form2")) {
$nome_arquivo = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],  "../legendofgames/documentos/games/".$nome_arquivo);
?>


<script>
opener.document.form2.strImage.value="<?php echo $nome_arquivo; ?>";
self.close();
</script>
<?php
}
else
{?>
```

Comment: 1.check that the target path is writable
2.check the max_post_size and max_file_size to be big enough
3.see if there is no error in $_FILES['userfile']['error']

Comment: Ok, it says that the file is not writable, how can I fix that?

Comment: best best way is a quick googling because fixing it depends on your Operating System.