# Upload image file to server failed

Tags: php

I am trying to upload images to my web server. Since that it is a free web server, instead of visiting its ftp server directly, I could only use one given software to connect to FTP server.

My problem is that I am trying to upload images to my server using "move_uploaded_file" function.  Below are the codes:

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["name"],
  "/www/99k.org/1/2/3/123shop/product_images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

I was given a error that permission denied. My question is that, is it possible to use move_uploaded_file function to upload files to a server that requires username and password

Comment: Apart from the fact that `ftp` is a protocol from the 70th and should be replaced by more modern alternatives wherever possible: if that really is a ftp server (it speaks the ftp protocol), then why are you limited in the client side software you use?!?

Comment: About your question to php's `move_uploaded_file`: that function does not _upload_ any files, it only _moves_ them afterwards from their temporary location to where you want to store them. So the upload has happened before, with or without authentication. So first you should check if the upload did indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

check for folder permissions, and you should be uploading temp file, like

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "/www/99k.org/1/2/3/123shop/product_images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

and check max_post_size and upload_max_size to big enough to upload.
some useful solutions available here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16390900/954924